# Android java listview adapter error with 2 activities

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have 2 activities with listview and when I go to activity B and back to A and click, I get error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131492961, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.example.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
```

When I need to call notifyDataSetChanged()? 
In my acticities or in ItemListBaseAdapter Class?

The code in my activities:

```
ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();
  final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                    lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), image_details));

                    lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                            Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        }
                    });
  private ArrayList<ItemDetails> GetSearchResults() {
    ArrayList<ItemDetails> results = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
    for(int i = 0;i<Code.size();i++) {
        ItemDetails item_details = new ItemDetails();
        item_details.setName(getString(R.string.newanswer));
        item_details.setItemDescription(Book.get(i) + " - " + getString(R.string.page) + " " + Page.get(i) + " " + getString(R.string.exercise) + " " + Exercise.get(i) + "\n" + getString(R.string.clicktoshow));
        item_details.setImageNumber(2000);
        results.add(item_details);
    }


    return results;
}
```

The ItemListBaseAdapter Class:

```
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemDetailsrrayList;


private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ItemDetails> results) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


}



public int getCount() {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
    if(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() == 1999) {
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.person);
    }
    else {
        if(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() == 2000) {
            holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        }
        else {


            byte[] a = itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getPicture();
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeByteArray(
                            a, 0,
                            a.length);
            holder.itemImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView txt_itemName;
    TextView txt_itemDescription;
    ImageView itemImage;
}}
```

Comment: Where calling `notifyDataSetChanged` method?

Comment: Why is the second constructor in the Adapter class empty? Also you are using `image_details` while setting the adapter on the listview but the other method adds items to a `result` object. Could you please explain on that? Or maybe paste the entire code for the Activity class.

Comment: It's a mistake. Mistakenly I copied twice this function. I edited the post.

Comment: What is `image_details` ? in your `listview.setAdapter`

Comment: Is `image_details ` full result when you set `lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), image_details));`

Comment: image details is:
ArrayList<ItemDetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();
(I edited the post)

Comment: I think result is made after listview set adapter so i think you set adapter in your `GetSearchResults` before returning value

Comment: Its working great. but with 2 activities with this listview, I get error when I go to activity B from activity A and return to A.

Comment: set listview adapter on resume and notifydataset changed

Comment: @Ron In your `ActivityA` go to A override onresume method and here you set your listadapter again

Comment: @Ron Have you check this solution ?

Comment: @Uit14bs I tried it but now all the data appear twice (it add the items again).

Comment: Ok app still crashes ?

Comment: Did you add this `  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @Uit14bs No. the app no crashed.

Comment: So your basic problem is resolved

Comment: @Uit14bs yes :) Why it is copied?

Comment: Now you can use saved instance for activity
Or remove adapter from oncreate
And  add it to onresume

Comment: @Uit14bs the adapter is only in onresume.

Comment: @Uit14bs Can you help me please?

Comment: Try this `if (lv1!= null && lv1.getAdapter() != null) {
            ((ItemListBaseAdapter) lv1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            lv1.invalidateViews();
        }` in the `onResume` method of your activity.

Comment: @NarayanAcharya With this code, its put the item of ListView B in ListView A. its not working

Comment: That sounds unlikely. If both the activities have different listviews(different ids) then that should not have happened. Data doesn't fly around in between activities like that. Maybe if you put code for both the activities up here, analysing it will become easier.